# Deinterlacing failed when encoding a file with h264

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, deinterlace

Tried using several different h264 encoders but all of them make it have this problem where there are horizontal glitches near movement. I tried using ffmpeg but couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

[image: Problem]

Video - its an MP4
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rCZ8r7W_MS7I2yh9YbqPG7qFP5cV2zuF/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated. I have the unrendered video in Premiere Pro if I need to render it differently or something. Please keep it simple as I do not have that great an understanding of video related tech/software.

Answer (score 0):

Most video players have got built-in deinterlacing. I have watched it on Google Drive and in QuickTime Player. Everything seems to be fine.

In VLC Media Player you can also choose between various deinterlacing methods.

HandBrake is a GUI-based transcoder basing on FFmpeg. It can encode H.264 and has got deinterlacing options. [Download](https://handbrake.fr)